# jQuery UI not working with imported XML data, Only with raw HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, jquery-ui

I am creating a document that fetches its data from an XML doc and displays it. I wanted to apply a simple jQuery UI accordion to it to make it neater to navigate but there seems to be some conflict with the the data being external. When I copy and paste the source in a separate document it works fine.

Here is the doc with XML: http://brettlewis.me/assets/experiments/xanimals/xmltest.html

Here is the doc with raw HTML: http://brettlewis.me/assets/experiments/xanimals/test.html

I thought using HEAD.JS would help by forcing the script to initialize after the XML was loaded, but that didn't do anything.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with XML vs HTML, I think it's related to the library you're using to load JS files and run scripts. I think it's calling the accordion widget before the DOM is fully loaded with the data. When I do `$("#animal").accordion("destroy").accordion()` in the Javascript console, it fixes it up.

Comment: I didn't mean to load those scripts twice. I took that out. I can't seem find the right place to call for the accordion still.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#animals').accordion();
```

is being called before the DOM is finished being populated with the external data.

Delete this:

```
head.ready("script", function() {
    $( "#animal" ).accordion();
});
```

and

```
, function() { $( "#animal" ).accordion();
```

from the first head.ready call.

Then add it in your callback after you are done building the DOM.

If you need to update the data at any point first destroy the current accordion and then rebuild it:

```
$('#animal').accordion('destroy');
$('#animal').accordion();
```